# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - tried all earlier soln not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, ssl, tls1.2

I am receiving "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

tried below codes

> ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
>
> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
> | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
> | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
> | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
>
> ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate {
> return true; };

code trying to call is below

```
           WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string urlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

When run the code without any TLS configuration in Windows Application it works. When i place the code in ASP.Net the error happening

Comment: What version and build number of Windows and .NET is the server using that is running ASP.Net?

Comment: @Charlieface framework 4.6

Comment: And Windows build number? Have you followed all the instructions in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#if-your-app-targets-a-net-framework-version-earlier-than-47)? You should really upgrade your .NET Framework version to 4.8.